# I updated my geth instance to 1.10.12-stable, but after update it is not syncing anymore

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I updated my geth instance to latest stable version (currently 1.10.12). After it stopped synchronization. It loads new data,  but the data is not synced.

When I attach to geth console. Here is the result of `eth.syncing`.

```
{
  currentBlock: 13645663,
  highestBlock: 13645748,
  knownStates: 759776557,
  pulledStates: 759776557,
  startingBlock: 13642218
}
```

The highest block is being updated, but current block is stuck at `13645663`.

Here is the logs of geth running.
I am periodically getting some errors.

```
INFO [11-19|10:11:11.854] Imported new block receipts              count=20  elapsed=46.095ms  number=13,642,881 hash=50a2b4..2fc589 age=8h24m53s  size=2.63MiB
INFO [11-19|10:11:12.009] Imported new block receipts              count=19  elapsed=40.526ms  number=13,642,900 hash=d19ba9..0969de age=8h19m55s  size=2.61MiB
INFO [11-19|10:11:12.197] Imported new block receipts              count=20  elapsed=38.788ms  number=13,642,920 hash=ba7bae..b24a64 age=8h15m45s  size=2.51MiB
INFO [11-19|10:11:12.384] Imported new block receipts              count=17  elapsed=33.753ms  number=13,642,937 hash=c9501f..667e53 age=8h11m     size=2.18MiB
INFO [11-19|10:11:12.384] State heal in progress                   accounts=0@0.00B slots=0@0.00B codes=1781@14.31MiB nodes=42,046,268@12.17GiB pending=1
INFO [11-19|10:11:12.637] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=32 static=0
INFO [11-19|10:11:22.829] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=35 static=0
INFO [11-19|10:11:26.191] Imported new block headers               count=1   elapsed=7.303ms   number=13,644,990 hash=8263a3..543997 age=1m34s
WARN [11-19|10:11:30.938] Rewinding blockchain                     target=13,642,941
INFO [11-19|10:11:31.056] Loaded most recent local header          number=13,642,941 hash=8d3ef8..5e80f6 td=34,737,602,273,369,506,724,624 age=8h10m15s
INFO [11-19|10:11:31.056] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0          hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184                 age=52y7mo2w
INFO [11-19|10:11:31.056] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=13,642,937 hash=c9501f..667e53 td=34,737,555,355,455,193,913,238 age=8h11m19s
INFO [11-19|10:11:31.056] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=13,642,938
WARN [11-19|10:11:31.056] Rolled back chain segment                header=13644990->13642941 fast=13642937->13642937 block=0->0 reason="syncing canceled (requested)"
INFO [11-19|10:11:31.396] State heal in progress                   accounts=0@0.00B slots=0@0.00B codes=1781@14.31MiB nodes=42,046,268@12.17GiB pending=1
WARN [11-19|10:11:31.396] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=4330cffeb30d641540e7f1e54db7f6f7af67a7f30efa9ab7a6f2ef3e97b4bc22 err="no peers available or all tried for download"
INFO [11-19|10:11:33.162] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=33 static=0
INFO [11-19|10:11:43.163] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=39 static=0
INFO [11-19|10:11:53.163] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=31 static=0
ERROR[11-19|10:11:56.780] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=04dfa983 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [11-19|10:12:00.963] Disabling direct-ancient mode            origin=13,642,937 ancient=13,529,647

INFO [11-19|12:40:41.487] State heal in progress                   accounts=118,187@6.17MiB  slots=141,437@10.53MiB codes=1824@14.72MiB nodes=43,256,951@12.53GiB pending=32314
INFO [11-19|12:40:49.809] State heal in progress                   accounts=118,380@6.18MiB  slots=141,501@10.53MiB codes=1824@14.72MiB nodes=43,258,393@12.53GiB pending=33054
INFO [11-19|12:40:53.864] Imported new block headers               count=1   elapsed=8.175ms   number=13,645,621 hash=154d5f..577225
ERROR[11-19|12:40:53.882] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=98998f1a err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [11-19|12:40:54.278] Imported new block headers               count=1   elapsed=7.340ms   number=13,645,622 hash=2f3ac0..445f26
INFO [11-19|12:40:55.331] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0    blockTasks=0   itemSize=236.74KiB throttle=1108
INFO [11-19|12:40:58.692] State heal in progress                   accounts=118,619@6.20MiB  slots=141,590@10.54MiB codes=1824@14.72MiB nodes=43,260,031@12.54GiB pending=33727
WARN [11-19|12:41:03.665] Unexpected trienode heal packet          peer=e38d81c4 reqid=1,164,924,289,101,288,635
```

Any ideas what can be the cause?

Comment: UPDATE: Solved the issue via a resync.

Comment: i am also having the same problem as you, have you ever solved it?

Comment: Yes, it seems the problem was the disk throughput. I deleted the chain and synced it again. That solved the issue.